# Not receiving push after reinstall the app

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush-android, push

We have an Android APP integrated with push (using subscriberKey feature).
When a user installs the app and registers to push, everything works fine (can receive push notifications). 
After uninstalling the App and reinstalling again, I cannot receive push notifications.
Using the Google REST api: https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send, when trying to send a push to a given device, the response is:

```
{
  "multicast_id": 6181628329120123506,
  "success": 0,
  "failure": 1,
  "canonical_ids": 0,
  "results": [
    {
      "error": "NotRegistered"
    }
  ]
}
```

So I made the following test:

1. Install the app fresh new and register with a new user, then send a push using  https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send, OK.
2. Uninstall the app and try to send a push, the response is the same as above: "error": "NotRegistered"
3. Reinstall the app and login with the same credentials as in 1), so the MC Android SDK method: ETPush.configureSdk(...).build() and ETPush.getInstance().setSubscriberKey(..) are called, then I try to send a push again and the response is the same as above: "error": "NotRegistered"

Has anyone experienced the same behaviour?

Comment: Which version of the SDK is being used?

Comment: The version is 4.4.1

Answer (score 0):

Check the LogCat for errors during SDK initialization.  If the SDK failed to initialize then it will not register with Google to receive push notifications.

Aside from that ...

Your Device ID in the Marketing Cloud system will change depending on the version of the SDK you're using.

Also, your device token from Google might change between installations.

Finally, if you install/un-install/re-install then you must be sure to wait 15 minutes after the finally installation for your new Device ID to propagate throughout the system.  Sends via the Marketing Cloud prior to the new installation's registration being processed would still target the the Device ID for the initial installation -- which, as noted above, may be tied to a now defunct device token from Google.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the app is the same so the SDK version is the same. I've checked and it seems the device is the same as well. If I re-register with a new subscriberKey, the SDK registers correctly the new contact and can receive push. I`ll check the deviceId and system token  if both cases, install/un-install/reinstall and install-register-unregister-register and let you know

Comment: @SebOB I know its a too late to ask but have you able to resolved the issue ?

Comment: @Vishvendu We saw the membership changed to not-opted in after unistalling the app. But it was with an old version of the SDK, we havent faced this with the latest.